# How do I create a array custom field for use with facetwp.com?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, bulk-import

I plan on displaying information on a range of laptop computers, including:

1. Make
2. Model
3. CPU
4. OS

Some laptop manufacturers let you choose the OS, between Windows 8 or Windows 8 Pro, say.

I thought I could build a website with Wordpress, and display laptops as WooCommerce products. Note: I don't intend on selling laptops, this is an informational website only.

The benefit of using Wordpress, I thought, would be the availability of something like [FacetWP](https://facetwp.com/), to add a list of facets/fields (such as CPU, OS) to refine the search with.

I intended importing the spreadsheet as a CSV with WP All Import + WP All Import WooCommerce.

However, I'm a bit confused at how to import the OS field as a custom field array.

WP All Import WooCommerce lets me import column fields as product custom fields, but **how do I format the OS column in the CSV so I can import it as an array in a custom field?**

**Will importing the OS column as an array into a custom field work with FacetWP?**

Not sure if this question is off-topic or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work, you simply have to separate your different OS with "|" in your CSV file. FacetWP will allow you to create a taxonomy that you'll be able to use.